# numpy array to list conversion issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For some reason, `evalRow(list(array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])))` and `evalRow([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])` give different results. However if I use `magicConvert` (here to debug this) instead of `list` to go from numpy array to list it works as expected:

```
def magicConvert(a):
  ss = str(list(a))[1:-1]
  return map(int, ss.split(","))

# You don't actually need to read these functions, just here to reproduce the error:
from itertools import *
def evalRow(r):
  grouped = map(
    lambda (v, l): (v, len(tuple(l))),
    groupby(chain([2], r, [2])))
  result = 0
  for player in (1, -1):
    for (pre, mid, post) in allTuples(grouped, 3):
      if mid[0] == player:
        result += player * streakScore(mid[1], (pre[0] == 0) + (post[0] == 0))
  return result

def streakScore(size, blanks):
  return 0 if blanks == 0 else (
    100 ** (size - 1) * (1 if blanks == 1 else 10))

def allTuples(l, size):
  return map(lambda i: l[i : i + size], xrange(len(l) - size + 1))
```

Comment: for me they gave the same result, `0`...

Comment: I believe it's better to use `tolist()` to convert between `numpy` arrays and `list`s. Using `list(some_array)` has to iterate over the numpy array and then create the list accordingly, while `tolist()` can probably avoid some overhead od the generic conversion.

Comment: Note that, when you do `list(array([0, 1, 2]))` you get a list `[0, 1, 2]` where elements are `numpy`s `int64`, not python's `int`. Using the `tolist()` method returns python's `int` instead. This may affect the operations you do and hence the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference in the behaviour is due to the fact that doing `list(some_array)` returns a list of `numpy.int64`, while, doing the conversion via the string representation (or equivalently using the `tolist()` method) returns a list of python's `int`s:

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: ar = np.array([1,2,3])

In [23]: list(ar)
Out[23]: [1, 2, 3]

In [24]: type(list(ar)[0])
Out[24]: numpy.int64

In [25]: type(ar.tolist()[0])
Out[25]: builtins.int
```

I believe the culprit is the `100 ** (size - 1)` part of your code:

```
In [26]: 100 ** (np.int64(50) - 1)
Out[26]: 0

In [27]: 100 ** (50 - 1)
Out[27]: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

In [28]: type(100 ** (np.int64(50) - 1))
Out[28]: numpy.int64
```

What you see is the `int64` overflowing, hence the result of the exponentiation are essentially "random", while python's `int`s have unlimited range and give the correct result.

To summary:

- If you want to convert between `numpy` and python data types use the proper methods, in this case `array.tolist()`
- Remember that `numpy`s data types have limited range, hence *you* should check for overflows and expect strange results in other situations. If you do not use the proper methods for conversion you might end up using `numpy` data types when you didn't expect (as in this case).
- **Never** assume it's a bug in python/`numpy`/a very widely used library. The chances to find a bug in such trivial cases in such well-tested and widely used softwares is *really small*. If the program gives unexpected results, 99.999% of the times it's because *you* are doing something wrong. So, before blaming on others try to check step by step what your program is doing.

Comment: About your 3rd point, I agree that this was trival in this case, but I'm getting paranoid in python after having encontered several known bugs in lxml. And the [issues list for numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) looks pretty scary to say the least...

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain If you check *any* serious project issue tracker you'll find thousands of issues. A lot of them are simply duplicates/closed. Many are feature requests etc. so the number of issues actually being bug reports is much smaller than what one might think. Anyway, it's impossible to write anything really big and complex without bugs. My point is: if you are doing trivial things the chances to find a bug are *really* small. Yes, it can happen sometimes. You should assume the error is in your code until you can prove otherwise. Doing the opposite takes longer to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it and it gave me differnet results. Don't ask me why, maybe a bug?

Anyway always use the `tolist()` function to convert a numpy array to a list.

```
evalRow(array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]).tolist()) == evalRow([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
#output: True
```

Comment: This still does not explain why list(.) is not working here but solved my issue :)